# webpack react process.env always empty (windows 10)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have read all of the articles here at stack overflow and about 200 more from google searches and i, for the life of me, can't get my head around process.env. No matter what i do it's always an empty object.

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        search: './src/search/search_index.js',
        // search: './src/search/search_index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "../website/public/javascript/react"),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
    }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env" : {
                'NODE_ENV': '"production"'
            }
        })
    ]
};

"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --content-base src/search",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
}
```

`console.log(process.env);` // from a render method in the running application started with `"npm start"`

Always returns `{}`

I am trying to get NODE_ENV set to production on my build and have had zero luck %NODE_ENV% show production but regardless i get the warning message in console about it running on a slower build to use NODE_ENV production.

To try and unwind what's happening i just wanted to see what my app was getting in process.env and it's an empty object. So then i tried hard coding it with defineplugin to again just test whats going on and it's the same result.

Been banging my head against this for about 3 hours now. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `DefinePlugin` configuration you're using replaces occurrences of `process.env.NODE_ENV` expressions in your code with whichever value you configure - it won't touch references to `process.env`, as you haven't told it to do anything with that exact expression - the configuration you're using is just shorthand for replacing multiple expressions which share a common root.

Webpack is detecting that you're referencing a global `process` variable and is injecting the [`process` mock](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser/blob/master/mock/process.js) from [node-libs-browser](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser), which as you can see defines an empty `env` object.

You can use [`node` Webpack config](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node) to control this. Adding `node: {process: false}` to your config will disable injection of a mock for `process`.

Comment: I tried it with plugins removed from the config file and it has the same result.

Comment: It's detecting that you're referencing a `process` global and injecting a mock object - this is enabled by default.

Comment: When I set process to false, I've got this `error process is not defined`

Comment: The node Webpack Config link in your answer appears to be dead.

Comment: The node Webpack Config link is now https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node