# How to use Gatsby env variables in a mdx file?

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to display Gatsby env variables in md file. I checked online what was the best way to do it, and using JSX in a md file (with the help of mdx plugin) seems to be the best option. For example, I want to map an array, coming from the env variables, in order to display all values. However, it is impossible to get access to any variables.

ex (in my mdx file): `<div>{process.env.MyVariable.map(el=>(<div>{el}</div>))}</div>`

error: `ReferenceError: process is not defined`

I started to add Gatsby [plugin env variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-env-variables/) on this [tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-11-21-how-to-convert-an-existing-gatsby-blog-to-use-mdx/). I double checked how to do it with this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6w9jjrnnjn?file=/gatsby-config.js:55-63). I can access to my variables inside my `.js` files, but not in my `.mdx` files.

What I am missing? Is it the best option to do it right?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Can you provide your code or your Sandbox? Not the one you based on.

Comment: I created a [github repository](https://github.com/fabiendv/gatsbyBlog). My .env.development is .sample

Answer (score 1):

`.env` variables are strings so, you can't loop them and display what's inside each position like an array. You can set something like this in your `.env.development`:

```
MESSAGES="message1, messages2, messages"
```

However, this would be one single string. You'll need to split them into a 3 position array by `let dotEnvArray = process.env.MESSAGES.split(',')`.

If you use try:  `MESSAGES=["message1", "messages2", "messages3"]` it will be treated as `MESSAGES= "['message1', 'message2', 'message3']"`.

What you are seeing here:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-env-variables`,
      options: {
        whitelist: ["MY_VAR", "MY_OTHER_VAR"]
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Is an array of .env variables isolated. According to this plugin's documentation:

> This will make `MY_VAR` & `MY_OTHER_VAR` available at runtime in your app
>   by accessing `process.env.MY_VAR` or `process.env.MY_OTHER_VAR`.

However, those variables haven't any value defined, you will need to set them in your `.env.development` file anyway. This is because Gatsby by default only exposes all variables prefixed with `GATSBY_`. Take a look to [Gatsby documentation about `.env` files](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) for further information.

Answering another part of your question, once you've set (in your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

By default, running `gatsby develop` Gatsby will take your `.env.development` variables and will expose them under `process.env.VAR_NAME`, always isolated and treated as a single string, just how your CodeSandbox shows.

To achieve what you want in your repository, just add your environment variables in your whitelist.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-env-variables`,
      options: {
        whitelist: ["ENDPOINTS"]
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I got your point. However, as you can see on my [github repository](https://github.com/fabiendv/gatsbyBlog), variables are still not allowed in my mdx file...

Comment: You need to name it `.env.development`. You can change the naming but by default, it concatenates `.env.ENV_NAME`. If you want to name it `.env.sample`, you will need to change the running script in `package.json`. Default environments are `.env.developemt` and `.env.production`.

Comment: Of course. It is because .env* are in my .gitignore. So I called it .sample to push it.
I will update it to prevent the confusion

Comment: Does your `.env.development` a variable called `ENDPOINTS` inside?

Comment: I forgot to rename it. But it doesnt change anything.. Variables are not readable from my example.mdx file

Comment: What's the output from `process.env`  and `process.env.NODE_ENV`? The first will show us if there are any environment variables there and the second will output the environment (to check if the file is correct).

Comment: Empty (in blog-post.js at line 42)

Comment: process.env.NODE_ENV equals to development

Comment: Did you try removing the plugin `gatsby-plugin-env-variables`?

Comment: No.. Why should I do that?

Comment: Same issue when I remove the `gatsby-plugin-env-variables`

Comment: That's it! Your variables will only be available if they are prefixed with `GATSBY_` (i.e: `GATSBY_ENDPOINTS`) if you don't want to do so, just use add it to your whitelist. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Oh ok I understood. But I still cannot access to the variable in my example.mdx which I just pushed

Comment: Even `process.env.GATSBY_API_URL`?

Comment: Yes. Still `ReferenceError: process is not defined`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741674/cant-access-gatsby-environment-variables-on-the-client-side what about this?

Comment: What if do you try to `console.log` outside a `return`? Try it where do you declare `const siteTitle = data.site.siteMetadata.title`

Comment: I checked it out earlier and it is useless because my problem comes from my mdx file. In my blog-post.js, every variables are working.. But they are not available in my example.mdx where :> `process is undefined`.

Comment: Then store them in a variable before and share that variable in your component.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the right way to do it? Seems to me not optimized at all

Comment: Of course, there's nothing wrong with creating a variable to store what's inside `process.env.NAME` and share it wherever you want, it's more readable indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For now, I let the question open to get other idea.

Answer (score 1):

For now I managed to achieve it only with intermediate JS config.

## 1. Create JS config wrapper:

```
// site-config.js

export const siteConfig = {
  siteUrl: process.env.GATSBY_SITE_URL,
  dashboardUrl: process.env.GATSBY_DASHBOARD_URL,
};
```

## 2. Use this middle config in MDX files

```
// pages/index.mdx
 
---
title: Getting started
description: How to get started?
---
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import { siteConfig } from '../../../site-config';


This is our <a href={siteConfig.dashboardUrl}>proxyly.io Dashboard</a>.
```