# Can't read environment variables in Heroku

Tags: angular, typescript, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy an app to Heroku. It's building correctly (using the heroku nodejs buildpack), but I can't access Heroku's environment variables. This is the environment file that is being used:

```
import * as process from 'process'

console.log(process); // Object containing numerous props (cwd, chdir, browser, etc.)
console.log(process.env); // Empty object but NOT undefined
console.log(process.env.BACKEND_URL); // Undefined

export const environment = {
    production: true,
    baseUrl: process.env.BACKEND_URL,
    apiBaseUrl: process.env.BACKEND_URL + '/api/v1/',
    cmsBaseUrl:  process.env.BACKEND_URL + '/content/pages/',
    verboseApiCalls: false
};
```

Build command that is being run:
`"postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod && npm install -g serve",`

Angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "front-end": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/front-end",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/assets/styles/partials"
              ]
            },
            "styles": [
              "src/styles-app-loading.scss",
              "src/assets/styles/catch.scss",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "front-end:build",
            "disableHostCheck": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "front-end:build:production"
            },
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "front-end:build:local"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "front-end:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/assets/styles/partials"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "front-end-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "front-end:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "front-end:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "front-end"
}
```

Package.json: (dont really know if it's relevant)

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod && npm install -g serve",
    "start": "serve dist/front-end/ -l $PORT",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.21",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^10.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.3.0"
  }
}
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41248996/7404090) answer, but could not find the referenced modules anywhere. I really don't know where to look, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the app.json file ([doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema)). 
When you want to deploy an app to Heroku, the app.json is read and env variables are set. Moreover you can specify the build, the addons (for example postgres) and the post-script commands that you want to execute.
Here is an example for your project :

```
    {
       "name": "Example",
       "description": "This app does one little thing",
       "success_url": "/",
       "scripts": {
          "postdeploy": "database create && database update"
         },
      "env": {
        "production": "true",
        "verboseApiCalls": "false"
      }
  }
```

One more step :), I push my app.json on my remote repository (github), and to deploy the app juste use the [following url](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button#testing-the-app-json-file) :

```
https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/yourNameOrOrganisation/yourRepository
```

Don't forget also to add a Procfile.
Hope it helps ;)